# don't know whats wrong stddev func line couldn't solve it, can you please advice me. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, standard-deviation

So I am trying to define function to calculate mean and st.dev (without packages) of a given series of numbers, also the function must be provided with a minimum of 2 numbers, where *arg means I can use any list of numbers>1

def avg(x,y,*arg):
return (x+y)/2 if len(arg)<1 else (x+y+sum(arg))/(2+len(arg))

```
def stddev(x,y,*arg):
    
    mu = (x+y)/2 if len(arg)<1 else (x+y+sum(arg))/(2+len(arg))
    return ([x - mu] ** 2/len(arg))**0.5
```

Comment: can you please explain what is *arg here

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: [See here for more advice on formatting/structuring your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

`[x - mu] ** 2/len(arg)` will throw an error since can't take power (using **) of a list only an int/float. Also optional arguments to a function should be listed as **args like this: `def avg(x,y,**args):`. x when passed into stddev() should be a float or if subtracting a scalar from a list use something like this: `[ele - mu for ele in x]`